# Leads and Lags in for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dynamic-programming

My dataframe crisisdata consists of many vectors: year, country, a, b, c

I want to create lags and leads for a, b and c in a for loop:

My attempt:

```
crisis_variables <- c("a", "b", "c")

for (var in crisis_variables){
  
  # add lags
  crisisdata[, (paste0("l",1:4, "_", var)):= shift(as.name(var),1:4), by=country]

  # add leads
  crisisdata[, (paste0("f",0:4, "_", var)):= shift(as.name(var),0:-4), by=country]
```

But in every lag and lead variables I only have NA values.

Comment: Is there a reason to reinvent the wheel instead of using `dplyr` `lag` and `lead` or `rle`?

Comment: `data.table::shift()` as used by the OP is faster and more flexible than `dplyr::lead` or `dplyr::lag`, so I don't see this as reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as.name` needs `eval` to return the value of the column (assuming 'crisisdata' is `data.table`)

```
library(data.table)
for (var in crisis_variables){
  
  # add lags
   crisisdata[, (paste0("l",1:4, "_", var)):= 
          shift(eval(as.name(var)),1:4), by = country]

  # add leads
  crisisdata[, (paste0("f",0:4, "_", var)):=  
      shift(eval(as.name(var)),0:-4), by = country]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the high flexibility of `shift` function to generate all lags and leads at once as follow:

```
# create column names
n = -4:4
cols = paste0(ifelse(n>0, "l", "f"), abs(n))
cols = paste0(cols, "_", rep(crisis_variables, each=length(cols)))   
# f4_a, f3_a, ..., l3_c, l4_c

# generate all lags and leads
crisisdata[, (cols) := shift(.SD, n), by=country, .SDcols=crisis_variables]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take my original approach, and wrap it in a flexible function:

```
f <- function(df, var, shifts, stem) {
  df[, (paste0(stem, abs(shifts),"_",var)):= shift(get(var), shifts), by=country]
}

for(col in c("a","b", "c")) {
  f(crisisdata, col, 1:4, "l")
  f(crisisdata, col, -1:-4, "f")
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this with `purrr::walk()` instead of a for loop:

```
purrr::walk(c("a","b","c"), \(v)  {
  coln = c(paste0("l",1:4,"_",v),paste0("f",1:4,"_",v))
  crisisdata[, (coln):= shift(get(v),c(1:4, -1:-4)), by=country]
})
```

Output:

```
      year country           a           b          c        l1_a       l2_a       l3_a       l4_a        f1_a        f2_a        f3_a       f4_a        l1_b       l2_b
     <int>  <char>       <num>       <num>      <num>       <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>       <num>       <num>       <num>      <num>       <num>      <num>
  1:  2000       A -0.56047565  1.84386201 -0.6647694          NA         NA         NA         NA -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.1292877          NA         NA
  2:  2001       A -0.23017749 -0.65194990  0.4854600 -0.56047565         NA         NA         NA  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774  1.7150650  1.84386201         NA
  3:  2002       A  1.55870831  0.23538657 -0.3756029 -0.23017749 -0.5604756         NA         NA  0.07050839  0.12928774  1.71506499  0.4609162 -0.65194990  1.8438620
  4:  2003       A  0.07050839  0.07796085 -0.5618764  1.55870831 -0.2301775 -0.5604756         NA  0.12928774  1.71506499  0.46091621 -1.2650612  0.23538657 -0.6519499
  5:  2004       A  0.12928774 -0.96185663 -0.3439172  0.07050839  1.5587083 -0.2301775 -0.5604756  1.71506499  0.46091621 -1.26506123 -0.6868529  0.07796085  0.2353866
 ---                                                                                                                                                                    
120:  2026       D -1.02412879 -1.13730362 -0.9454088 -0.84970435 -0.6407060  0.1056762  0.3011534  0.11764660 -0.94747461 -0.49055744 -0.2560922  1.49606067 -0.5021987
121:  2027       D  0.11764660 -0.17905159  0.8569230 -1.02412879 -0.8497043 -0.6407060  0.1056762 -0.94747461 -0.49055744 -0.25609219         NA -1.13730362  1.4960607
122:  2028       D -0.94747461  1.90236182 -0.4610383  0.11764660 -1.0241288 -0.8497043 -0.6407060 -0.49055744 -0.25609219          NA         NA -0.17905159 -1.1373036
123:  2029       D -0.49055744 -0.10097489  2.4167734 -0.94747461  0.1176466 -1.0241288 -0.8497043 -0.25609219          NA          NA         NA  1.90236182 -0.1790516
124:  2030       D -0.25609219 -1.35984070 -1.6510489 -0.49055744 -0.9474746  0.1176466 -1.0241288          NA          NA          NA         NA -0.10097489  1.9023618
           l3_b       l4_b        f1_b        f2_b        f3_b        f4_b       l1_c       l2_c       l3_c       l4_c        f1_c        f2_c        f3_c        f4_c
          <num>      <num>       <num>       <num>       <num>       <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>       <num>       <num>       <num>       <num>
  1:         NA         NA -0.65194990  0.23538657  0.07796085 -0.96185663         NA         NA         NA         NA  0.48545998 -0.37560287 -0.56187636 -0.34391723
  2:         NA         NA  0.23538657  0.07796085 -0.96185663 -0.07130809 -0.6647694         NA         NA         NA -0.37560287 -0.56187636 -0.34391723  0.09049665
  3:         NA         NA  0.07796085 -0.96185663 -0.07130809  1.44455086  0.4854600 -0.6647694         NA         NA -0.56187636 -0.34391723  0.09049665  1.59850877
  4:  1.8438620         NA -0.96185663 -0.07130809  1.44455086  0.45150405 -0.3756029  0.4854600 -0.6647694         NA -0.34391723  0.09049665  1.59850877 -0.08856511
  5: -0.6519499  1.8438620 -0.07130809  1.44455086  0.45150405  0.04123292 -0.5618764 -0.3756029  0.4854600 -0.6647694  0.09049665  1.59850877 -0.08856511  1.08079950
 ---                                                                                                                                                                  
120: -0.7886220 -0.7815365 -0.17905159  1.90236182 -0.10097489 -1.35984070  0.3781678 -0.2097932  0.8176594  1.0246732  0.85692301 -0.46103834  2.41677335 -1.65104890
121: -0.5021987 -0.7886220  1.90236182 -0.10097489 -1.35984070          NA -0.9454088  0.3781678 -0.2097932  0.8176594 -0.46103834  2.41677335 -1.65104890          NA
122:  1.4960607 -0.5021987 -0.10097489 -1.35984070          NA          NA  0.8569230 -0.9454088  0.3781678 -0.2097932  2.41677335 -1.65104890          NA          NA
123: -1.1373036  1.4960607 -1.35984070          NA          NA          NA -0.4610383  0.8569230 -0.9454088  0.3781678 -1.65104890          NA          NA          NA
124: -0.1790516 -1.1373036          NA          NA          NA          NA  2.4167734 -0.4610383  0.8569230 -0.9454088          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)
crisisdata = data.frame(
  year = rep(2000:2030, 4),
  country = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=31),
  a = rnorm(124),
  b = rnorm(124),
  c = rnorm(124)
)
```